# Game development on android emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

I have corei7 @1.73GHz with 6GB Ram, and the emulator is really slow. 
How do you guys prefer to develop games ? on an emulator or real device?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Slow Android emulator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)

Answer (score 3):

Easy: on a real device.  But there are lots of reasons why you need both.  A device is way faster and reflects the software you will actually encounter.  An emulator is endlessly versatile and you can turn on pedantic runtime options.  So go with the device when you need quick turnaround, emulator for deep debugging, device to make sure you aren't encountering a quirk in the emulator, and emulator to make sure you aren't encountering a device-specific behavior.